# Changing x-axis labels in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

ive got ggplot (geombar), with names of the months on x-axis.i have some data from different days. But i would like to have the names on the axis corresponding to the specific dates.

```
Date.          Percent.    Category
2020-02-03.    30.         Apple
2020-02-03.    25.         Banana
2020-02-03.    15.         Citron
2020-02-03.    30.         Orange
2020-02-07.    40.         Apple
2020-02-07.    20.         Orange
2020-02-07.    40.         Banana
2020-04-12.    65.         Apple
2020-04-12.    35.         Banana
```

Ive got 80 dates from one year

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=Category, y=percents, x=date)) +
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

Comment: hi! can you please add d reproducible example of your data ( u can copy paste the output of dput() command). Can you also be more specific what names you need to change ( from what name to what name). and include what you have tried already

Answer (score 1):

I assumed this would be a duplicate but I was not able to find this question on stackoverflow, so here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Date          Percent    Category
2020-02-03    30         Apple
2020-02-03    25         Banana
2020-02-03    15         Citron
2020-02-03    30         Orange
2020-02-07    40         Apple
2020-02-07    20         Orange
2020-02-07    40         Banana
2020-04-12    65         Apple
2020-04-12    35         Banana", header = TRUE)

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

ggplot(df, aes(fill=Category, y=Percent, x=Date)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  scale_x_date(labels = unique(df$Date),
               breaks = unique(df$Date)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

This excellent answer by @teunbrand provides another approach to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746906/12957340